# How to find out whether Hyper-V is currently enabled/running

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v

How can I find out whether Hyper-V is currently running on my Windows 8.1 Pro System?

Reason: Some installs automatically enable Hyper-V (e. g. the Visual Studio Android Emulator addons). I am mostly using VMWare and VBox for Virtualization, and since Hyper-V is a Hypervisor (virtualizing host too), I want to avoid conflicts (double virtualization).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can check if the services are running:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> `services.msc`
Look in the list for all services beginning with `Hyper-V`. If any of them are `Running`, it's on. (Specifically, the core of it I believe is labelled Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management)

You can check the system log to see if any activity has occurred [guide here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941154.aspx):

1. Open Event Viewer. Click Start, click Administrative Tools, and then click Event Viewer.
2. Open the Hyper-V-Hypervisor event log. In the navigation pane, expand Applications and Services Logs, expand Microsoft, expand Hyper-V-Hypervisor, and then click Operational.
3. If Windows hypervisor is running, no further action is needed. If Windows hypervisor is not running, perform the following steps.
4. Open the System log. (In the navigation pane, expand Windows Logs and then select System.)
5. Look for events from Hyper-V-Hypervisor for more information. For example, event ID 41 indicates a problem with the BIOS configuration: “Hyper-V launch failed; Either VMX not present or not enabled in BIOS.” (To filter for these events, from the Actions pane, click Filter Current Log, and then for Event sources, specify “Hyper-V-Hypervisor”.)

Comment: Thank you! The services way seems quickest to find out. For the last way, I would need the servername, it did not work with the name of my host or localhost (command returned "error: description = not found").

Comment: @AndreasReiff Fair point, will remove this option.

Comment: Wrong. Hyper-V can be deactivated by a boot option. The service "vmms" will be running anyway if it's installed. So this isn't useful. I need another method that works.

Comment: Thanks. In my case (Windows 10 + Intel Core 2 Quad Q9550), I figured out, through the System Log, that `Hypervisor launch failed; Second Level Address Translation is required to launch the hypervisor`. This is true, Q9550 lacks SLAT. Will get VirtualBox then.

Comment: As ygoe states, If you set in bcdedit hypervisorlaunchtype    Off, this still says running despite hypervisor being off.

Answer (score 46):

Run Powershell as Administrator.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Run the command:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

If it is enabled, you'll see the answer like this:

```
FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V
DisplayName      : Hyper-V Platform
Description      : Provides the services that you can use to create and manage virtual machines and their resources.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :
```

More info [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/get-windowsoptionalfeature) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v).

Comment: What's the difference of this and `get-service | findstr vmcompute` ? This one says Disabled, and the other one says Running.

Comment: But Windows Sandbox cat enbale Hyper-V anyway.

Answer (score 15):

Powershell : get-service | findstr vmcompute

Running  vmcompute          Hyper-V Host Compute Service

Comment: If you set in bcdedit hypervisorlaunchtype    Off, this still says running despite hypervisor being off.

Comment: @user5389726598465 I've turned it off via bcedit and it does not show up in the output here. Had you actually turned Hyper-V off properly?

Comment: Also works without Admin rights

Answer (score 4):

In my case with the cmdlet

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Hyper-V was enabled but hypervisorlaunchtype was off

So I checked the status of hypervisorlaunchtype with (look for `hypervisorlaunchtype`):

```
BCDEdit /enum
```

And I enabled hypervisorlaunchtype with the following command as administrator:

```
Bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Answer (score 0):

In "windows start search" search for "windows features" and you will find Hyper-v check box.

Now you can not only check the current status, but you also can change it.