# Hyper-V Does Not Work However VMWare Does

Tags: vmware, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I recently rebuilt my main Hyper-V server along with the other two servers and since my entire network is still running Windows 7, I decided to swap 2012 R2 out with 2008 R2. Now my two secondary servers are working great.

The problem lies in the main one. Hyper-V will not initialize a VM. To make sure I hadn't messed up the BIOS I uninstalled Hyper-V and installed VMWare Workstation. It has no problem with VMs. I really do not want to have to use VMWare though as all my VMs are already in Hyper-V format and to be honest I much prefer Hyper-V to VMware.

For reference the machine is clean install and both VMs are fresh. I have also verified my install media and confirmed that it is good.

Exact Error -

```
[Window Title]
Hyper-V Manager

[Main Instruction]
An error occurred while attempting to start the selected virtual machine(s).

[Content]
'New Virtual Machine' could not initialize.

The virtual machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running. 

[Expanded Information]
'New Virtual Machine' could not initialize. (Virtual machine ID 3C2AAECF-136C-4BB8-A2F8-8690E97F5ED0)

The virtual machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running.  The following actions may help you resolve the problem:

1) Verify that the processor of the physical computer has a supported version of hardware-assisted virtualization.

2) Verify that hardware-assisted virtualization and hardware-assisted data execution protection are enabled in the BIOS of the physical computer.  (If you edit the BIOS to enable either setting, you must turn off the power to the physical computer and then turn it back on.  Resetting the physical computer is not sufficient.)

3) If you have made changes to the Boot Configuration Data store, review these changes to ensure that the hypervisor is configured to launch automatically.



[^] Hide details  [Close]
```

System Running Hyper-V :
[image: ImageOne]

System Running VMWare :
[image: ImageTwo]

Comment: Post the error.  Also, look at the CPU for the box running hyper-v and make sure it's suppported.

Comment: I have now updated my question to include the exact error, and while not in Microsoft's list of officially supported CPUs, it works on 2012 R2 and 2016 RTM.

Comment: And I am going to let it fully patch tonight and see if anything changes tomorrow.

Comment: Did you verify that Hyper-V was in working condition and correctly installed? The error message would indicate it's not. Your reasoning with downgrading to 2008 R2 is beyond me. [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/22690b57-b5ba-4551-a9d2-5a4e409c566c/check-whether-hyperv-is-running-stopped-or-not?forum=winserverhyperv) could help you to check if it's running or [this superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/1026651/how-to-find-out-whether-hyper-v-is-currently-enabled-running) (easier?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of messing around I accidentally tripped a chkdsk which showed me that I had quite a few bad sectors on my hard disk. I went out and bought and new one and it fired up just fine.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.